# Error push/pull on github: Unable to resolve github.com

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I have been using Tortoisegit on my Windows 7 laptop to access my GIT repository since 2and getting this error. I tried to access github.com page on the browser (Chrome & IE) and even there I get the error: "This webpage is not available". Finally I tried even ping from command line and even that cannot resolve github.com.

I do not use any proxy and this is my personal laptop with just Windows firewall and defender running on it.

Any ideas to fix this issue?

Srini

Comment: So your problem is that your computer can't access github.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message shows that its a problem with your computer or isp . if its not a problem with your computer, try contacting your internet service provider.

if you are an indian user, there is a country wide [controversial ban](http://techcrunch.com/2014/12/31/indian-government-censorsht/) on websites including github . 
until they lift the ban, you can by pass it using **[google  dns](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)** or using a vpn .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Was not aware of this news. Will try the workarounds you suggested.

Comment: @user2094305 no problem :) . if you find the answer helpful you can mark it accepted . ( click on the green check mark by the side of answer ) . cheers .