# How to Replicate a Repository from Github to Gitlab with Frequent Updates?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Not sure if you heard the news that Department of Telecom India has blocked access to github.com (Don't ask me why).

I was wondering if it is possible to replicate a github.com repository to our gitlab server which has access to github.com and is accessible in our Indian office as well. So that every new update on github is replicated in gitlab (Manually or Automatically) but updates from gitlab don't need to go back to github.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like  mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739188/error-push-pull-on-github-unable-to-resolve-github-com/27739503#27739503) , you can bypass the block using **google dns** or a **vpn** .

if you want to mirror your github repo to gitlab, follow this thread on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/531931/mirror-github-to-gitlab) . the idea is to mirror the github repo and add a cron job to pull new updates ever hour . but the downside is that you can't push updates to the repo .

Comment: Thanks Sojan!! I will try this and let you know. Seems like it is what i have been looking for :)

Comment: @Rohit good luck . hope it helps , please mark the answer complete if it does ;)